# glMapBufferRange gives me an access violation

Tags: c++, opengl, access-violation

I just got a laptop with an Intel HD4000 "graphics card" and my code that works on my stationary computer with an HD6950 gives me an access violation. I changed from version 4.4 to 4.0 since the HD4000 only supports up to 4.0.

Looking at the OpenGL wiki for it says it can only guarantee alignment from version 4.2 and up, so I'm thinking that may be the issue but I'm not sure and I don't know how to deal with it

I took [this code from open.gl](http://open.gl/drawing) and modified it to use GLFW to test with:

```
// Link statically with GLEW
#define GLEW_STATIC

// Headers
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>
#include <iostream>

#include <windows.h>

// Shader sources
const GLchar* vertexSource =
"#version 150 core\n"
"in vec2 position;"
"in vec3 color;"
"out vec3 Color;"
"void main() {"
"   Color = color;"
"   gl_Position = vec4(position, 0.0, 1.0);"
"}";
const GLchar* fragmentSource =
"#version 150 core\n"
"in vec3 Color;"
"out vec4 outColor;"
"void main() {"
"   outColor = vec4(Color, 1.0);"
"}";

int main()
{
    if(!glfwInit())
        return -1;

    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 4);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 0);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);

    GLFWwindow* window = nullptr;
    window = glfwCreateWindow(800, 600, "OpenGL", NULL, NULL);

    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);

    // Initialize GLEW
    glewExperimental = GL_TRUE;
    int glewRes = glewInit();
    if(glewRes != GLEW_OK)
    {
        glfwTerminate();
        OutputDebugStringA(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(glewGetErrorString(glewRes)));
        OutputDebugStringA("\n");
        return -2;
    }

    // Create Vertex Array Object
    GLuint vao;
    glGenVertexArrays(1, &vao);
    glBindVertexArray(vao);

    // Create a Vertex Buffer Object and copy the vertex data to it
    GLuint vbo;
    glGenBuffers(1, &vbo);

    GLfloat vertices[] = {
        -0.5f, 0.5f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, // Top-left
        0.5f, 0.5f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, // Top-right
        0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, // Bottom-right
        -0.5f, -0.5f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f  // Bottom-left
    };

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo);
    //glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertices), vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertices), NULL, GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);
    GLfloat* mappedData = static_cast<GLfloat*>(glMapBufferRange(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0, sizeof(vertices), GL_MAP_WRITE_BIT | GL_MAP_INVALIDATE_RANGE_BIT));

    GLenum error = glGetError();
    error = glGetError();
    error = glGetError();

    if(mappedData == NULL)
    {
        glfwTerminate();
        return -3;
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < ARRAYSIZE(vertices); i++)
    {
        mappedData[i] = vertices[i];
    }
    glUnmapBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER);

    // Create an element array
    GLuint ebo;
    glGenBuffers(1, &ebo);

    GLuint elements[] = {
        0, 1, 2,
        2, 3, 0
    };

    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, ebo);
    glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(elements), elements, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    // Create and compile the vertex shader
    GLuint vertexShader = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
    glShaderSource(vertexShader, 1, &vertexSource, NULL);
    glCompileShader(vertexShader);

    // Create and compile the fragment shader
    GLuint fragmentShader = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
    glShaderSource(fragmentShader, 1, &fragmentSource, NULL);
    glCompileShader(fragmentShader);

    // Link the vertex and fragment shader into a shader program
    GLuint shaderProgram = glCreateProgram();
    glAttachShader(shaderProgram, vertexShader);
    glAttachShader(shaderProgram, fragmentShader);
    glBindFragDataLocation(shaderProgram, 0, "outColor");
    glLinkProgram(shaderProgram);
    glUseProgram(shaderProgram);

    // Specify the layout of the vertex data
    GLint posAttrib = glGetAttribLocation(shaderProgram, "position");
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(posAttrib);
    glVertexAttribPointer(posAttrib, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 5 * sizeof(GLfloat), 0);

    GLint colAttrib = glGetAttribLocation(shaderProgram, "color");
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(colAttrib);
    glVertexAttribPointer(colAttrib, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 5 * sizeof(GLfloat), (void*)(2 * sizeof(GLfloat)));

    while(!glfwWindowShouldClose(window))
    {
        glfwPollEvents();

        // Clear the screen to black
        glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        // Draw a rectangle from the 2 triangles using 6 indices
        glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 6, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);

        // Swap buffers
        glfwSwapBuffers(window);
    }

    glDeleteProgram(shaderProgram);
    glDeleteShader(fragmentShader);
    glDeleteShader(vertexShader);

    glDeleteBuffers(1, &ebo);
    glDeleteBuffers(1, &vbo);

    glDeleteVertexArrays(1, &vao);

    glfwTerminate();

}
```

For some reason whenever I use glMapBufferRange it gives me an access violation at `mappedData[i] = vertices[i];`.

If I simply use glBufferData or glMapBuffer it works fine

Comment: Why do you call `glGetError()` 3 times in a row?

Comment: @ColonelThirtyTwo No real reason, I just didn't remove it

Comment: @ColonelThirtyTwo: Actually the proper way to query OpenGL errors is to do a `GLenum glerr; while( GL_NO_ERROR != (glerr = glGetError()) ) { handle_error(glerr); }` – OpenGL errors can accumulate and you must call `glGetError` in a loop until `GL_NO_ERROR` is returned.

Comment: @datenwolf: To be fair, several errors being recorded is possible only as a special case in "distributed implementations", which is neither the case with the OP (single HD4000 system) nor with probably 99% (or maybe 99.99%) of all users.

Comment: @Damon Not entirely. GLEW generates an error when calling `glewInit()` in some configurations, so I made 3 calls just to check if there were any other errors besides the obvious one. Since it was just a test program I didn't bother with doing things properly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows just installed 38 updates and now it works